# How can I display only time instead of date and time in matplotlib chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to display a line stock chart of a day of market activity of UBER. For that I'm using the yfinance database, taking the 'Datetime' index for the x axis and the 'Open' column for the y axis and plotting it to matplotlib:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = yf.download(tickers='UBER', period='1d',  interval='5m', rounding=2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data.index, data['Open'])
ax.grid()

plt.show()
```

yfinance database(shortened):

```
>>> data
                            Open   High    Low  Close  Adj Close  Volume
Datetime                                                                
2021-12-30 09:30:00-05:00  42.29  42.70  42.20  42.69      42.69  372810
2021-12-30 09:35:00-05:00  42.65  42.77  42.48  42.51      42.51  241993
2021-12-30 09:40:00-05:00  42.49  42.85  42.40  42.50      42.50  325688
...
2021-12-30 13:10:00-05:00  43.12  43.17  43.08  43.15      43.15   80142
2021-12-30 13:15:00-05:00  43.15  43.22  43.14  43.22      43.22  130573
2021-12-30 13:20:19-05:00  43.23  43.23  43.23  43.23      43.23       0
```

This is the result:
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XiDN.png)

The problem is that I don't want to display the date(12-30) on the x axis before the time. Ideally, I'd like to only display the hours and minutes (10:00, 11:00,...,16:00)

I tried changing `data.index` to `data.index.time` but it gives me this error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'datetime.time'
```

This happens because the object type apparently changes and matplotlib can't plot the new type

```
>>> type(data.index)
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>

>>> data.index
DatetimeIndex(['2021-12-30 09:30:00-05:00', '2021-12-30 09:35:00-05:00',
           '2021-12-30 09:40:00-05:00', '2021-12-30 09:45:00-05:00',
                                     ...  
           '2021-12-30 15:50:00-05:00', '2021-12-30 15:55:00-05:00',
           '2021-12-30 16:00:00-05:00'],
           dtype='datetime64[ns, America/New_York]', name='Datetime', freq=None)

>>> type(data.index.time)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

>>> data.index.time
[datetime.time(9, 30) datetime.time(9, 35) datetime.time(9, 40)
...
datetime.time(15, 50) datetime.time(15, 55)
datetime.time(16, 0)]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))` might work for you

Comment: I copied the line. It is now displaying only the time just as I wanted, but it goes from 15:00 to 21:00 when the database goes from 9:30 to 16:00. Is this possible?

Comment: This is probably related to localisation, as you seem to explicitly use NY time, while the displayed time could be universal time.